# Sqlite Open Helper work fine in android 2.3 but dont work in android 4

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a code to work with database in sdcard, it work fine in Android 2.3 device but not work in android 4 devices, in android 2.3 a database is created and or opened on path on sdcard, and in android 4 a database is created or opened in default datadir of application in phone. Code Below ...

```
public class dBeeHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public final static String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 59;
public static final String  DATABASE_FILE_PATH =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
public static tables db = new tables();
private Context mcontext;
    public dBeeHelper(Context context) {
    super(new ContextWrapper(context) {
            public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, 
                int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {

                // allow database directory to be specified
                File dir = new File(DATABASE_FILE_PATH + "/Manager/");
                if(!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                Manager manager = ((Manager)getApplicationContext());
                if (dir.canWrite()){
                    manager.setDbLocation(dataFiles.Location.SdCard);
                }else{
                    manager.setDbLocation(dataFiles.Location.Phone);
                }
 return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( DATABASE_FILE_PATH + "/Manager/" + DATABASE_NAME, null,
SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            }
        }, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mcontext = context;
}
```

When I debug the application, in Android 2.3 the openOrCreateDatabase is fired, in android 4 it not is fired!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I change the contructor and it was worked in android 4 too. 
Below code changed.

```
 private static Manager manager;
 public dBeeHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, getpath(context)  + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mcontext = context;
 }

    public static String getpath(Context context){
        manager = (Manager) new ContextWrapper(context).getApplicationContext();
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Manager";
        File dir = new File(path);


        if(!dir.exists()) {
            if (dir.canWrite()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }else{
                manager.setDbLocation(dataFiles.Location.Phone);
                return "";
            }
        }
        manager.setDbLocation(dataFiles.Location.SdCard);
        path = path + "/";
        return path ;
    }
```